# AS3 Loader objects loads same swf it's invoked from ignoring URL

Tags: actionscript-3

My main file is test.swf. My external file is ext.swf. The code to invoke loader is:

```js
function init() 
{
    // somethin else
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("ext.swf");
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);
    loader.load(urlRequest);
}


protected function onSwfLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var initiator:LoaderInfo = LoaderInfo(event.target);
    var initiatorLoader:Loader = initiator.loader;
    var content:DisplayObject = initiatorLoader.content;
}
```

The problem is that in onSwfLoaded I see that loaderUrl property of the loader is ... "main.swf"! And url is ext.swf as expected. 
But content is that of main.swf

All examples I found use almost identical code. Where that source-of-caller-swf thing came from puzzles me greatly and gives me lots of pain, please help.

Network tracing shows that ext.swf is downloaded correctly, but loader.content has contents of main.swf inside it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('ext.swf');
var loader:Loader = new Loader();  
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfLoaded);
    loader.load(url_request);

function onSwfLoaded(event:Event):void {
    addChild(loader.content);
}

// you can also add the loader directly to the display list
// addChild(loader);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: It readds my main.swf into my main.swf, and so on into recursion according to trace

Comment: yep, that's what your code did.
Also I don't see how it's different from mine except using closure

Comment: I tested that code, and it's working, it's the standard code used to import and swf into another ! I don't understand how it can include your main.swf into itself ! Are you sure there isn't another thing that you forgot to tell us about it ?

Comment: Seems to have been caused by two 'Main' classes in those swfs. After renaming one of 'Main's to MainExt, the issue went away

Comment: Now I can understand ;)